# PhantomJS randomly does not exit (using Selenium with Python)

Tags: python, selenium, phantomjs, celery

I'm using [selenium-python](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org) with PhantomJS. The code is pretty much like this:

```
from selenium.webdriver import PhantomJS
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
driver = PhantomJS()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
driver.get(url)
while True:
    // scrap the page
    try:
        driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.next')[0].click()
    except: break
    wait.until(expected_conditions.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.loading')))
    wait.until(expected_conditions.invisibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.loading')))
driver.quit()
```

I use a celery task which runs this code periodically. The problem is that from time to time there are some stale phantomjs processes. When I look into celery logs the task is completed successfully without any errors but the phantomjs process is still running.

Some extra info:

- I'm using Python 3.2
- I'm using Celery 3.1 with beat
- I'm using Debian Wheezy
- I compiled PhamtomJS from source and created a symbolic link like this: `ln -s /opt/phantomjs/bin/phantomjs /usr/local/bin/`

Can someone suggest a way to debug and find out who's fault is this?

Comment: You could replace PhantomJS with your favorite Browser and put it on a virtual display unter Linux with xvfbwrapper. If those processes persist it might be a problem of selenium.

Comment: That would be that last solution to switch to another browser (say Firefox or Chromium with XVFB). Is there any other way to debug and find out who's fault is this?

Comment: As you probably read compiling phantomjs is not recommended if the binaries fit your needs. What about installing it from the debian repos or use the precompiled files?

Comment: PhantomJS is not included wheezy repos. In fact at first I went for precompiled binaries but the performance was awful, then I compiled it from source and and it's now working just fine. (I think that's because precompiled binaries are build in a CentOS box)

Comment: I have not use celery before, are you sure celery will display all error message for you? For your code, I think if an exception occurs when running `wait.until`, `driver.quit()` will not be executed.

Comment: That's a possible reason. I will check celery logs and let you know.

Comment: Yes, that was the problem! I looked into celery logs and there was some failed tasks (timeout exception when running `wait.until`) being retried several time!

Comment: @WKPlus just create an answer to get your bounty :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not use celery before, are you sure celery will display all error message for you? For your code, I think if an exception occurs when running `wait.until(...)`, `driver.quit()` will not be executed.

Comment: Thanks :) That was a stupid mistake! The point is celery was retrying tasks, so it kept getting worse and all i was seeing was some `RetryException` messages.